# How to solve gradient-exploding in YOLO v1

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, nan, yolo

Now I am trying to train object detection - YOLOv1 using [this](https://github.com/yakhyo/YOLOv1-pt) code. At the beginning I was using `momentum` and `weight_decay` but the training loss after couples of epochs becomes `NaN`. As far as I know it's because of gradient exploding, so I have searched some ways to get rid of this `NaN` then I ignored `momentum` and `weight decay`. As a result I did not get any `NaN`, however my model could not converge as I expected. When I calculated `mAP` it was only **0.29.** I am using VOC 2007 and 2012 data for training and as a test set VOC 2007 test.

So my questions are followings:

- How can I get rid of `NaN` while training?
- Where can I get best training configurations?
- Is gradient exploding is normal in Object Detection task?
- Is it normal in YOLOv1 getting 1.1Gb weights after training?

Would appreciate any suggestions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking your code, I saw after the first epoch, you would set the learning rate to `0.01` until epoch 75. In my opinion, that large learning rate is the main reason made your parameters became vanishing/exploding. Normally, the learning rate is scaling around `0.001` with the factor of `2,1,0.1`.

[Follow the config in this repo](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/blob/master/cfg/v1/yolo-full.cfg) (the most famous repo implement YOLOv1 according to [paperwithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/you-only-look-once-unified-real-time-object)), you can see their configurations setup. You can follow their hyper-parameters, `momentum=0.9` and `decay=0.0005` in your question.

**Note:** please be careful that the batch norm momentum in Tensorflow = 1 - momentum in Pytorch.

Finally, your number of parameters before and after training should be the same, so if your model is heavier/lighter after the training process, it means there is something wrong with your training code.

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer. So I should set the `momentum` to 0.9 or 0.1? At first, I used `momentum=0.9` and `decay=0.0005` but got `nan`.

Comment: as I said, the reason for your Nan maybe come from your large learning rate, reduce it to 0.001 and train it again. The `momentum` you are talking about is the momentum in optimization or in EAM or in batch norm layer? Please clarify it

Comment: The `momentum` is in BatchNorm

Comment: Set it to 0.1 for the formula `x_new = (1 - momentum) * x + momentum * x_t`, follow [this documents](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html)

Comment: I will train with this params then if everything is okay I will choose your answer as correct answer.

Comment: There was not a big change

Comment: Once I trained it with changing fc layer then got 0.37 mAP(much better than before). Now training it again without last convolutional layer. [link](https://github.com/yakhyo/YOLOv1-pt/blob/1aa5504924c57f31f6e53a4bd162fe83b82f75ac/nets/yolo.py#L32)

Comment: Good to hear that. Sorry I don't have time to review it all, just be sure your code is similar to the link in my answer. You set all `LeakyReLU` is `in_place` except some lines, [example](https://github.com/yakhyo/YOLOv1-pt/blob/1aa5504924c57f31f6e53a4bd162fe83b82f75ac/nets/yolo.py#L27), can I know why?

Comment: thanks for your help. There is no any exact reason  for that. I think I forgot to change it.